# How to evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty\cdot e^{i\epsilon}}^{\infty\cdot e^{i\epsilon}}\, dz\,e^{-iz^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty\cdot e^{i\epsilon}}^{\infty\cdot e^{i\epsilon}}\, dz\,e^{-iz^2}?$$

Can we evaluate this integral using the stationary phase approximation?

Comment: I'd try to shift the contour to something like $\int_{-i\infty}^{i \infty} e^{z^2}dz =i \sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you very much for your comment. But how did you do that shift? Can you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: Define "$\infty$ times anything" please.

Comment: @Dr.MV That only indicates the integral contour in complex integral.

Comment: Written that way, it has no meaning.  Do you mean instead to write $\pm \infty +i\epsilon$?

Comment: @Dr.MV This convention is actually used in particle physics. It means that we rotate the real axis by a angel $i\epsilon$. Maybe we need a figure to make it clearer.

Comment: You mean angle $\epsilon$, do you not?  And you really mean, $\lim_{L\to \infty} \int_{-Le^{i\epsilon}}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz$.

Comment: For $\epsilon>0$, the contour passes from the third to first quadrant.  And since $e^{-iz^2}=e^{2xy}e^{-i(x^2-y^2)}$ is unbounded as $xy\to \infty$, the integral diverges.  Did you want the integrand to be $e^{+iz^2}$ instead?  Or, did you want the left sided limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-}$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The integral $\displaystyle \lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-Le^{i\epsilon}}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz$ diverges for all $0<\epsilon<\pi/2$.**
>
> To see this, we enforce the substitution $\displaystyle z=e^{i\epsilon}t$ to find
>
> $$\begin{align}\int_{-Le^{i\epsilon}}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz&=e^{i\epsilon}\int_{-L}^L e^{-ie^{i2\epsilon}t^2}\,dt\\\\
> &=e^{i\epsilon}\int_{-L}^L e^{\sin(2\epsilon)t^2}e^{-i\cos(2\epsilon)t^2}\,dt\tag 1
> \end{align}$$
>
> For $0<\epsilon<\pi/2$, the exponential growth of the integrand on the right-hand side of $(1)$ renders the integral divergent as $L\to \infty$.  If $-\pi/2<\epsilon<0$, however, then the integral converges as $L\to \infty$.  We now proceed to evaluate the limit of the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ when $-\pi/2<\epsilon<0$.

Let $L>0$ and $-\pi/2<\epsilon<0$ be fixed and $C_\pm$ be the closed contour comprised of the straight line segments (i) from $\pm L$ to $\pm Le^{i\epsilon}$, (ii) from $\pm Le^{i\epsilon}$ to $0$, (iii)  from $0$ to $\pm L$.

Since $e^{-iz^2}$ is entire, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_{C_\pm } e^{-iz^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{\pm L}^{\pm Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz+\int_{\pm Le^{i\epsilon}}^{0}e^{-iz^2}\,dz+\int_{0}^{\pm L}e^{-iz^2}\,dz \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ reveals

$$\int_{-Le^{i\epsilon}}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz=\int_{-L}^L e^{iz^2}\,dz +\int_{L}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz-\int_{-L}^{-Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz \tag 3$$

As $L \to \infty$, the second and third integrals on the right-hand side of $(3)$ approach $0$.  Hence, for $-\pi/2<\epsilon<0$,

$$\lim_{L \to \infty}\int_{-Le^{i\epsilon}}^{Le^{i\epsilon}}e^{-iz^2}\,dz=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^L e^{-iz^2}\,dz =(1-i)\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark